# array to string conversion error, need to explode and then implode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode, implode

I want to explode an array, read each value and print them back in an array...

I dont understand where i am getting wrong. Please help me..this is my code..

I am getting an array to string conversion error

```
$query="SELECT categories FROM shops";
$result = mysql_query($query);  
while($column = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $categories=explode(",",$column['categories']);
    foreach($categories as $value){
        $new_query="SELECT name from categories where id='$value'";
        $name = mysql_query($new_query);    
        $name_column= mysql_fetch_assoc($name);
        array_push($shops_list,$name_column);

    }
}
echo implode(",",$shops_list);
```

Comment: quick hint on performance, don't do queries inside loop if not neccessary.

Comment: Learn how to use SQL Joins, and you won't need to do this inefficient query looping: learn how to use MySQLi or PDO as well... then you won't need to use deprecated libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$shop_list` is not defined, before using it in this line `array_push($shops_list,$name_column);`. And, this line

```
    array_push($shops_list,$name_column);
```

needs to be, as you need to mention the key `name`,

```
    array_push($shops_list,$name_column['name']); //or better
    $shop_list[] = $name_column['name'];
```

Comment: why the loop is not breaking after each id?

Comment: `foreach($categories as $value){` will loop through all the values in array `categories`. isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

```
$name_column = mysql_fetch_assoc($name);
$name_column = $name_column['name'];
```

`name_column` is an array.

`shops_list` is never initialized.

You should use `[]` instead of `array_push`.

Answer (score 1):

The other guys hit it on the nose, but when you did your array push on $name_column, since $name_column is an array, you end up with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => boo
        )
)
```

Obviously doing an implode on that is going to not work.

That being said, what you really need to do here is not keep your category mappings as a comma delimited string in the database. Standard DB architecture dictates you use a mapping table.

- Table shops
- Table categories
- Table shop_category_map that has shop_id and category_id

Answer (score 1):

use [group_concat](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) to retrieve values.  and after getting the result, use them directly for searching. like

```
$result_array = explode(",",$row['category']);

    foreach($result_array as $ra)
    {
    //sql command. fetch here.
    $new_query="SELECT name from categories where id='$value'";
    $name = mysql_query($new_query);    
    $name_column= mysql_fetch_assoc($name);
    $shops_list[] = $name_column;
    }
```

try else go for better solution

Answer (score 1):

// explode an array and then implode until a particular index of an array

```
$a = '192.168.3.250';
$b = explode('.',$a);
$ar = array();

for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++)
{
   array_push($ar,$b[$i]);
}

$C = implode($ar,'.');
print_r($C);
```